# Monitor a mailbox for new email

Tags: php, email

Is there a way i can monitor a mailbox for new email and do something for instance

```
  function onEventNewEmail()
     {
    //copy a file to a specified server on new email arrival
    echo "File copied to the server you specified...\n";
     }
```

when a new email arrives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a cronjob that periodically checks for new mails and then executes a function. PHP is interpreted, hence you can't really talk about "events".

Write a small PHP script that does what you want and then create a cronjob (or service) that executes every X [time interval] and does what you want.

Comment: Couldn't you run a long-term PHP process using inotify (if available)? http://php.net/manual/en/book.inotify.php

Comment: I am currently thinking of that but getting emails to be delivered in text format,i.e email1,email1.txt is the tricky part that i am trying out.And by the way,the emails must be delivered in a folder you can watch i.e /home/iboxFolder